# ¿Cómo puedo cargar varios HTML sin que se interpongan entre sí?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Cada vez que llamo un html diferente con el método `load()` se interponen los audios de diferentes páginas. ¿Cómo puedo cargar varios HTML dentro de un HTML sin que se interpongan entre sí?

Éste es el código HTML:

```
<section class="channels">

   <ul>
      <li><button id="ElektroXploit">Ch.2 - ElektroXploit</button></li>
      <li><button id="Classic_Hits">Ch.3 - Classic Hits</button></li>
    </ul>

 </section>
```

Y el JS con el que cargo el HTML:

```
 $("#ElektroXploit").click(function(){
    $(".reproductor").load("2Elektro.html");
});



 $("#Classic_Hits").click(function(){
    $(".reproductor").load("3Classic.html");
});
```

[image: aca tienen el codigo de Hitlist que a su vez es la de elktroxploit tambien, ya que es solo cambio de nombre en el radioname:]

[image: y este es el codigo del plugin de la radio, con la que funciona (aclaro que este codigo no lo hice yo, se compro a un servicio)]

Comment: Hola, bienvenid@ a StackOverflow en español, te sugiero hacer el [tour] para que tengas una mejor idea sobre el funcionamiento de la pagina y puedas dar a conocer tu pregunta de mejor manera. También puedes revisar [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para lo mismo. Saludos.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el código de 2Elecktro.html y 3Classic.html? Y también, ¿dónde tienes `.reproductor` en tu código HTML? Sería ideal que pudieras poner esa información para poder crear un [mcve] y poder reproducir el problema.

Comment: dispones de skype asi puedo mostrarte por ahi? pasa que el codigo que dispongo de los reproductores son privados, y solo tengo acceso yo

Comment: Si quieres ayuda en Stack Overflow, debes poner los datos en la pregunta en Stack Overflow en lugar de sacar a los usuarios fuera del sitio. Esto es así porque si otro usuario se encuentra con un problema similar y en lugar de tener aquí la solución la tienes en tu Skype, no le sirve de ayuda (porque no tiene acceso). La idea es compartir conocimiento y no limitarlo. Completa el [tour] y lee sobre cómo crear un [mcve] para más información.

Comment: SO es del conocimiento público por lo que debes tratar tu problema por otro medio, te sugiero busques a quienes te suministraron el reproductor "privado" que seguramente ellos podrán ayudarte, suerte!! ;))...

Comment: Les pido mil disculpas, es mi primera vez en Stackoverflow y cometi un error, ahora voy a subirles donde tengoo todo detallado, asi pueden ver el error y reitero.. mil disculpas.

Comment: En la primera imagen esta el codigo de Hitlist, que es la mimsma que elektroxploit. el nombre es cuestion de cambiar el radioname:.

Comment: y la segunda imagen es el codigo del plugin de la radio, la cual el codigo no lo hice yo. sino que es un plugin comprado y ya vino asi desordenado. Disculpen si recurri a subir imagenes, no entiendo muy bien el tema de poner comentarios e insertar codigo en SO

Comment: creo que el planteamiento se puede invertir: antes de cargar un nuevo "html" "descargas" los otros, habrá un corte en el sonido pero te aseguras que no se superpongan

Comment: con que metodo o funcion podria hacer eso? si me decis el modo estaria muy agradecido. Desde ya muchas gracias